# OpenGL only loading when a remote desktop session is open

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, remote-desktop

I have a program that is loading OpenGL via GLFW. The program will be used for offscreen rendering, so I need it to work in the background.

```
GLFWwindow* window;

glfwInit();
glfwSetErrorCallback(GLFWErrorCallback);

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, GLFW_FALSE);

window = glfwCreateWindow(1920, 1080, "OpenGLWindow", NULL, NULL);
if (window == NULL)
{
    cerr << "Failed to open GLFW window." << endl;
    return RETURN_ERR;
}
```

When I run this from a RDP session, the `glfwCreateWindow` call succeeds. After loading OpenGL and calling `glGetString(GL_RENDERER)` I can see that it is using my GPU (GeForce GT 730/PCIe/SSE2), and not a remote display adapter or Mesa3D or anything else.

but if the RDP session is closed, the `glfwCreateWindow` call fails. The GLFW error callback is :

> Error code 65542: WGL: The driver does not appear to support OpenGL

I installed the latest Nvidia drivers for my GPU but they are never loaded.

What could cause GLFW to only be able to load the drivers in one case, but not the other?

Comment: maybe the issue is the context version? does it work if you change it to default 1.0? the docs say it will try to use the latest version of your driver then

Comment: Same issue if I change it to 1.0. Also it wouldn't explain why it would behave differently during a RDP session and when not